# 500 Internal Server Error en JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

el error del titulo me sale ya cuando es accesible desde el exterior, es decir cuando ya está "abierto" al publico, pero obviamente lo tengo como oculto; Alguien sabria el origen del error ya que me da error en la linea **397** y la linea **398** de un codigo JavaScript aqui está el código

```
function refrescar_mensajes_N_v(){
return new Promise(resolve => {
    setInterval(
        function() {
            var notifica = true;
            request = $.ajax({
                url: ".refresh_n_v.php",
                type : "POST",
                data : notifica,
                success: function (response) {
                    response = JSON.parse(response);

                    //console.log($.isEmptyObject(response) );
                    if($.isEmptyObject(response)==false){

                        for(var i in response){

                            $('#mi_panel').html(
                                $('<div/>', {'class':'panel panel-primary','id':'mensaje_'+response[i].id}).append(
                                    $('<div/>',{'class':'panel-heading','html':'Mensaje Nuevo! - '+response[i].fecha}),
                                    $('<div/>', {'class':'panel-body'}).html(response[i].mensaje),
                                    $('<div/>',{'class':'panel-body'}).append($('<button/>',{'type':'button','class':'btn btn-success','onclick':'dejar_visto('+response[i].id+')','html':'OK'}))));
                        }
                    }else{
                        // $('#mi_panel').replaceWith('<h3 id="no_mensajes">No tienes Mensajes nuevos</h3>');
                    }

                  },
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
              }
            });   
        }, 60000);
    });


}
```

Ya me disculparán un poco la falta te tabulación hacer copy + paste en este medio se me hace un poco troll, la llamada a esta función está en un **$(document).ready** y se ejecuta cada minuto para ver si tiene mensajes nuevos o no y a su vez lo puede dejar el mensaje en visto, el error sale en el los dos **console.log**, y no entiendo la causa, ya que es local funciona.

En donde hago la el POST tengo esto:

```
<?php
include ('includes/sesion.inc.php');


$nivel[]=1;
$nivel[]=2;
controlar_acceso_permitido($nivel);

$lista_mensajes = lista_mensajes('',$conn);
$listado = [];
$usuario_log  = $_SESSION['grieo_1_000']['usuario'];
//var_dump($lista_mensajes['count']);

for ($i=0; $i < $lista_mensajes['count']; $i++) {
    if ($lista_mensajes[$i]['accion']=='NO_VISTO' && $usuario_log['id'] == $lista_mensajes[$i]['id_usuario']) {

        $listado[] = array(
            'id' => $lista_mensajes[$i]['id'], 
            'fecha' => $lista_mensajes[$i]['fecha'], 
            'mensaje' => $lista_mensajes[$i]['mensaje'], 
            'accion' => $lista_mensajes[$i]['accion'], 
            'estado' => $lista_mensajes[$i]['estado'], 
            'status' => $lista_mensajes[$i]['status'] );
    } 

}
echo json_encode($listado, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

es hacer una consulta a la base de datos, recogerlos y guardarlos a un Array que luego la vuelvo formato JSON, no tiene mayor complejidad.

Gracias por su atención y ojalá puedan ayudarme :)

**UPDATE:**

He elvidado añadir que tengo un codigo muy semejante el cual solo recoje un número y lo muestra estas funciones se ejecutan asincronamente, eso creo, el caso es que si no ejecuto este codigo, pero si ejecuto el enterior, el error está ahi el codigo de ahroa sin funciona tanto como en local como en exterior el anterior donde formulo la pregunta no.

```
function refresca_notificaciones(){
 return new Promise(resolve => {
    setInterval(
        function() {

            var notifica = true;
            var respuesta = []
            //console.log("HOLA KE ASE");
            request = $.ajax({
                url: ".refresh_num_no_vistos.php",
                type : "POST",
                data : notifica,
                success: function (response) {
                if(response != 0){
                    $('#n_visto').removeClass('oculta').html(response);

                }else{
                    $('#n_visto').addClass('oculta');
                }

              },
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
              }
            });
        }, 60000);
    });
```

Comment: El "internal server error" indica que el error ha ocurrido en el servidor. Revisa los logs del servidor para obtener más información del error, y pon la información relevante aquí.

Comment: Pues está como dificil la cosa ya que nadie me puede facilitar los logs del servidor, la otra cosa, es que tengo un codigo muy parecido el cual solo me devuelve un número.

Comment: Intenta lo siguiente: Edita el archivo `refresh_n_v.php` y agregar esta línea al principio de todo `<?php error_reporting( E_ALL ); ?>`. Luego abre un tab en el navegador y accede a dicho archivo directamente (eg: `http://dominio/path/refresh_n_v.php`)

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda el error es **30719** ahi que deberia hacer?

Comment: @juank Eso no es un error, **30719** no nos dice nada de nada. ¿probaste a abrir el archivo directamente escribiendo la url en el navegador?  Todos los revisores almacenan el Log de errores en el un lugar, si ko lo encuentras, pregunta a tu proveedor o revisa la documentación del revisor que estés usando. Tampoco podemos determinar cuales son las líneas  397 y 398, indícanoslas.  Por otro lado las url que pones en los ayax creo que pueden darte problemas tal y como las tienes escritas, es raro que empiecen con un punto.

Comment: @Xerif LE he puesto que Imprima `error_reporting( E_ALL ); ` y me aparece un inte dentro de unos parentesis el numero que he puesto, y los archivos .PHP los tienen asi por la empresa, aparte de que si no se usan para nada importante como una vista pues funciona bien, otra parte es que estoy usando una especie de Framework de PHP que se llama smarty asi que menos problemas por ese lado jaja, y ahora pues no sé que mas hacer la verdad, ya que mi jefe diche que no es problema del servidor. y no em dija tacar nada del mismo, de igual manera gracias :)

Comment: y los de las lineas 397 y 398, con los console.log() que imprime el erroe 500 y el Internal Server Error, y pues... eso es muy confuso jaja